# Python, как из списка сделать словарь

Tags: python, list, словари

Как из списка типа ['a', 's', 'd', '1', 's', 'd', 'w', 'e', 'q'] сделать словарь такого вида: {'a': 2, 'b': 0 .... }, то есть сколько раз повторяется элемент в списке - такое число добавить в словарь.

Примечания: словарь **можно НЕ** строить из элементов что в списке, можно взять готовый скелет, пример:

```
{'a': 0, 'b': 0, 'c': 0, ...}
```

но **если лучше или легче** из элементов, которые в списке - пожалуйста.

**UPDATE**

['a', 's', 'd', '1', 's', 'd', 'w', 'e', 'q'] - это не пример данных)

Тут список может быть и следующий:

['=', 'w', 'r', 'p', 'f', ';', 'a', 'e', 'e', '[', 'w', 'q', 'r', "'", 'q', 'r', '3', 'caps lock', ';', 'D', 'A', 'S', 'D', 'shift', 'alt', 'ctrl', 'F', '.', 'C', 'R', ']', 'Q', '=', '3', '1', '2', '3', 'F', 'A', 'S', 'R', 'ctrl', 'C']

Это обычный ввод с клавиатуры и мне нужно как раз сложить это в словарь и отправить в базу данных.

Comment: А список ключей какой - все буквы английского алфавита в нижнем регистре?

Comment: все равно не понял - вам надо из списка сделать частотный словарь? и чем тогда не устраивают приведённые примеры? вы привели пример ввода - приведите пример того, что должно получиться на выходе

Comment: @CrazyElf, Обновил, список - любой ввод из клавиатуры, посмотрите пожалуйста, я обновил

Comment: @Zhihar (Возьму первые 9 символов) На Выводе: {'=': 1, 'w': 1, 'r': 1, 'p': 1, 'f': 1, ';': 1, 'a': 1, 'e': 2}

Comment: и чем не устраивает тогда приведённые мной и CrazyElf коды?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

если из элементов списка, то можно сделать очень просто:

```
arr = ['a', 's', 'd', '1', 's', 'd', 'w', 'e', 'q']

res = dict((i, arr.count(i)) for i in arr)

print(res)
```

если из скажем всех латинских букв и цифр, то

```
import string

arr = ['a', 's', 'd', '1', 's', 'd', 'w', 'e', 'q']

res = dict((i, arr.count(i)) for i in string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits)

print(res)
```

можно конечно использовать `map` еще, но код длиннее получается:

```
res = dict(map(lambda i: (i, arr.count(i)), arr))
```

**P.S.**

и конечно сразу стоит сказать, что если есть **жесткие** требования к скорости работы алгоритма, то лучше использовать другой подход, который сводит вызов `count` к минимуму (чтобы не выполнять лишние команды), например так:

```
res = {}

for i in arr:
    if i not in res:
        res[i] = arr.count(i)
```

теперь `count` будет вызываться только 1 раз на уникальный элемент из списка

можно сделать еще более оптимально - ведь count подсчет начинает вести с самого начала списка, а это не требуется ибо список мы уже просматриваем, тогда код будет выглядеть так:

```
res = {}

for i in arr:
    res[i] = 1 if i not in res else res[i] + 1
```

в этом случае мы заполняем словарь по мере продвижения по списку - т.е. выполняем минимум действий

Comment: Я обновил вопрос **Update**, посмотрите пожалуйста, возможно теперь Вы поймете что мне нужно было на самом деле, и тогда скажете за каким способом лучше ?

Comment: почему бы в первых вариантах не использовать `set(arr)`?

Comment: @Danis, в принципе можно, но опять же - если нет требований к скорости выполнения, то зачем? результат от этого другим не будет, а визуально код усложнится

Comment: @Zhihar поправьте меня, если не прав: разве for i in arr: res[i] = res.get(i, 0) + 1 не будет быстрее, чем for i in arr: res[i] = 1 if i not in res else res[i] + 1 из Вашего ответа? сложность та же, но константа меньше: не нужно искать в увеличивающемся res

Comment: @Jack_oS,надо потестировать но очень похоже вы правы

Answer (score 2):

Воспользуйтесь методом словаря [.get()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get). Он возвращает значение по ключу, если таковой есть в словаре, или *None* по-умолчанию, если ключа нет (и никогда не бросает исключения), но можно изменить *None* на свое значение. И оформите в виде функции для универсального использования:

```py
def counter(my_list: list) -> dict:
    result = {}

    for i in my_list:
        result[i] = result.get(i, 0) + 1
    
    return result
```

тогда при:

```
my_list = ['=', 'w', 'r', 'p', 'f', ';', 'a', 'e', 'e', '[', 'w', 'q', 'r', '"', 'q', 'r', '3', 'caps lock', ';', 'D', 'A', 'S', 'D', 'shift', 'alt', 'ctrl', 'F', '.', 'C', 'R', ']', 'Q', '=', '3', '1', '2', '3', 'F', 'A', 'S', 'R', 'ctrl', 'C']
```

результат будет следующим:

```
>>> counter(my_list)
{'=': 2, 'w': 2, 'r': 3, 'p': 1, 'f': 1, ';': 2, 'a': 1, 'e': 2, '[': 1, 'q': 2, '"': 1, '3': 3, 'caps lock': 1, 'D': 2, 'A': 2, 'S': 2, 'shift': 1, 'alt': 1, 'ctrl': 2, 'F': 2, '.': 1, 'C': 2, 'R': 2, ']': 1, 'Q': 1, '1': 1, '2': 1}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ну вот, например. Только я поменял `'1'` на `'a'`, а то иначе что-то не сходится в задании и `'a': 2` не получится:

```
from string import ascii_lowercase

d = {k: 0 for k in ascii_lowercase}
for k in ['a', 's', 'd', 'a', 's', 'd', 'w', 'e', 'q']:
    d[k] += 1

print(d)
```

Вывод:

```
{'a': 2, 'b': 0, 'c': 0, 'd': 2, 'e': 1, 'f': 0, 'g': 0, 'h': 0, 'i': 0, 'j': 0, 'k': 0, 'l': 0, 'm': 0, 'n': 0, 'o': 0, 'p': 0, 'q': 1, 'r': 0, 's': 2, 't': 0, 'u': 0, 'v': 0, 'w': 1, 'x': 0, 'y': 0, 'z': 0}
```

Comment: Я обновил вопрос **Update**, посмотрите пожалуйста, возможно теперь Вы поймете что мне нужно было на самом деле, и тогда скажете за каким способом лучше ?